# Pagination With realtime database in firebase when Child is same

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am having a problem with pagination with firebase

I am retrieving a limit of 5 results each time:

Showing you the problem with an example will be easier:

```
"myDb":{
  "products": {
      "uid1" : {
        "name" : "hello",
        "uid"  : "uid1",
        "size" : "1"
      }
      "uid2" : {
        "name" : "hello",
        "uid"  : "uid2",
        "size" : "2"
      }
      "uid3" : {
        "name" : "hello",
        "uid"  : "uid3",
        "size" : "34"
      }
      "uid4" : {
        "name" : "hello",
        "uid"  : "uid4",
        "size" : "4"
      }
      "uid5" : {
        "name" : "hello",
        "uid"  : "uid5",
        "size" : "15"
      }
      "uid6" : {
        "name" : "hello",
        "uid"  : "uid6",
        "size" : "50"
      }
  }
}
```

of course this is not my real data but now let me show you my query, I am using angularfire.

```
  getDatasByQuery(path:string, query:string){
    return this.db.list(path, (ref) => {
        return (ref.orderByChild('name').startAt(query).limitToFirst(5))
    })
  }
```

So what I actually do is take thevalue of the `name` property in the last results  and make another query with it to paginate. Only problem is that `name` equals to `"hello"` all the time.

of course I could increase the limit but the main problem would remain the same

I would like the user to search by `name` attribute and paginate results, as you might have understood at this moment the only thing I get are the 5 first results where `name` equals `"hello"` and never reach the sixth.

so

`first query ==> ['uid1', 'uid2', 'uid3', 'uid4', 'uid5'] => second query => exactly the same results`

any help is greatly appreciated, please let me know if you need more explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `startAt` method takes an optional second parameter, which is the **key** of the node to start at in case there are multiple matches for the first value.

So if you want to start at `uid4` after ordering on `name` and filtering on `hello`, that'd be:

```
ref.orderByChild("name").startAt("hello", "uid4");
```

The `uid4` here is the **key** of the node to start at, typically referred to as a disambiguation key.